# APEX_ITEM displays only one row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a form region "*Form on a SQL query*" with this query

```
SELECT 
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(1,TEAM_MEMBER) TEAM_MEMBER, 
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,HOURS) HOURS
FROM APEX_TEAM_MASTER
WHERE TEAM_DATE = :P2_TEAM_DATE 
AND UPPER(TEAM_LEAD) = UPPER(:P2_TEAM_LEAD)
ORDER BY 1
```

> TEAM_MEMBER and HOURS are the exact columns in the APEX_TEAM_MASTER table

The **:P2_TEAM_DATE** and **:P2_TEAM_LEAD** are select lists. When i run the page and select values in the lists, the form displays just one row of text boxes.

The purpose of this page is, a manager can login to this application, select a date and a team lead under him, which lists the members under the lead. He can then record the hours each team member worked for the day. There are multiple team leads under each manager and different number of team members under each team lead. So the form has to be dynamic.

Comment: What happens when you run the query in sqlplus or SQL Developer with appropriate values for `P2_TEAM_DATE` and 'P2_TEAM_LEAD`?

Comment: I get an output of 4 rows.

Comment: I would turn on debugging, check your session state and make sure those values are what you think they are. Is your `TEAM_DATE` a `DATE` field in your table?

Answer (score 0):

What you described looks more like an **Interactive Grid** (IG) (or former Tabular Form). There's no need for you to reinvent that functionality, so - switch to the IG and let Apex take care about everything else.